# How can i get a right quantity of sections in tableview. Swift, realm

Tags: ios, swift, realm

I have a property "day" in realm database, here i save all days, when a user makes some transactions. Exactly the quantity of days i need to count to get a right quantity of sections. Now it looks like one section for each transaction, I want that there's one section with all transactions for a day. My realm model:

```
class Items: Object {
@objc dynamic var Amount = 0.0
@objc dynamic var category = ""
@objc dynamic var type = Bool()
@objc dynamic var month = Int()
@objc dynamic var day = Int()
```

}

```
typealias Sections = [(quantity: [Int], name: String, items: [Items])]
func getAllItems() -> [Items] {
    var array: [Items] = []
    let objects = realm.objects(Items.self)
    for object in objects {
        array.append(object)
    }
    return array
}
func getSections() -> Sections {
    var sections: Sections = []
    let data = getAllItems()
    var temp = [Items]()
    var summ: [Int] = []
    
        for item in data {
            for item2 in data {
                if item2.day == item.day {
                    summ.append(item.day)
                    temp.append(item)
                }
            }
            sections.append((quantity: summ, name: "\(item.day)", items: temp))
            temp = [Items]()
        }
    return sections
    }

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
    RealmModel.shared.getSections()[section].name
}

func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    RealmModel.shared.getSections().count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return RealmModel.shared.getSections()[section].name.count
}
```

In fact, it all works, except "numberOfSections". I get them like this: [incorrect quantity of sections, I need one section for one day](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bCuJL.png). I can't understand how can i get only "summ" from getSections() in numberOfSections() or how can i get correct quantity the other way.

Comment: Why don't you just store the days in a List property? Then you can get the number of days with `let count = daysList.count`. Or perhaps create a 'Transaction Day' model that contains all of the transactions for that day within a List property. Maybe if you can include you're realm models we could help simplify this.

Comment: @Jay, added realm model. Also, i think, i need to get data for tableview from one array to avoid mistakes. But i'm glad to look at your solution.

Comment: Ok, that helps. I added an answer that should greatly simplify what you're doing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your for loop can work like you want cause you continue iterate on item with same day property as some items before. And your `numberOfRowsInSection`  method can't work properly cause you count on name property of section instead of items property. Although I don't have all informations on your model, that's how I would do: (Like say in another response, it's better to save sections and items instead of getting data at each call of table view data source and delegate)

```
typealias Sections = [(quantity: [Int], name: String, items: [Items])]
func getAllItems() -> [Int: [Items]] {
    var array: [Int: [Items]] = [:]
    let objects = realm.objects(Items.self)
    for object in objects {
        if Array(array.keys).contains(object.day) {
            var items = array[object.day]
            items.append(object)
            array[object.day] = items
        } else {
            array[object.day] = [object]
        }
    }
    return array
}
func getSections() -> Sections {
    var sections: Sections = []
    let data = getAllItems()

    for (key, value) in data {
        sections.append((quantity: value.count, name: "\(key)", items: value))
    }
   
    return sections
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
    RealmModel.shared.getSections()[section].name
}

func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    RealmModel.shared.getSections().count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return RealmModel.shared.getSections()[section].items.count
}
```

Comment: my model: 
    class Items: Object {
    objc dynamic var Amount = 0.0
    objc dynamic var category = ""
    objc dynamic var type = Bool()
    objc dynamic var month = Int()
    objc dynamic var day = Int()
}

Comment: also there are some mistakes, how can i solve them? Picture of code: https://yadi.sk/i/bz4MOFkUudhtIg
Thank you for your help! I have been doing this for a week already and can't finish

Comment: I edited the code to correct mistake. I had not changed the type of the return of the function getAllItems

Comment: thank you for your help, it's like the best after New Year present! Last question, how to make, that transactions in a section store like then newer, then higher. Cause now the oldest transaction is on the top of section.

Comment: Something like this: `sections.sorted { $0.name > $1.name }` before `return sections` in getSections function

Answer (score 0):

try solution with completionHandler:

```
typealias Sections = [(quantity: [Int], name: String, items: [Items])]
func getAllItems() -> [Items] {
    var array: [Items] = []
    let objects = realm.objects(Items.self)
    for object in objects {
        array.append(object)
    }
    return array
}
func getSections(completionHandler completion: ((_ quantity: Int) -> Void)?) -> Sections {
    var sections: Sections = []
    let data = getAllItems()
    var temp = [Items]()
    var summ: [Int] = []
    
        for item in data {
            for item2 in data {
                if item2.day == item.day {
                    summ.append(item.day)
                    temp.append(item)
                }
            }
            sections.append((quantity: summ, name: "\(item.day)", items: temp))
            temp = [Items]()
        }
    if let tCompletion = completion {
        tCompletion(temp.count)
    }
    return sections
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
    RealmModel.shared.getSections()[section].name
}

func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    getSections() { quantity in
        return quantity
    }
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return RealmModel.shared.getSections()[section].name.count
}
```

Comment: I think, i shouldn't give anything for getSections() to the entrance, because there are a lot of mistakes

Answer (score 0):

Try to compute sections only once and save into an array bar that you can use in table view data source and delegate.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the objective is to take an array of realm objects, determine the number of unique days with those objects and use them as section headers in a tableView. So the tableView would look something like

```
Day 1
   item
   item
   item
Day 2
   item
   item
   item
```

if that's the case, here's the easy way to do that. Assume you've loaded items from Realm into an array so it looks like this

```
let itemArray = [i0, i1, i2, i3, i4, i5, i6, i7, i8, i9]
```

Then add a separate array to be used as the section headers, called sorted day array

```
let dayArray = itemArray.map { $0.day } //all of the day properties
let daySet = Set(dayArray) //a unique set of day properties
let sortedDayArray = Array( daySet).sorted() //cast the set to a sorted array
```

so the sortedDayArray will be the unique day numbers sorted. From there to get the number of sections

```
func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    sortedDayArray.count
}
```

and to get the title for any particular section

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
        let dayNum = sortedDayArray[section]
        let title = "Day \(dayNum)"
        return title
}
```

and then to get the number of rows in a section

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return itemArray.filter { $0.day == section }.count
}
```